# Date Time value is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I am using **Bootstrap DatetimePicker** and I can select date and time. But when I click a date it's it nos asking me for time. I mean I need to click the **clock** icon then I can set the time.

Another problem is when I store the date and time in the database and try to show the value in **DateTime Picker text field it's not showing the value**. I can see the value from inspecting the browser. Why it's not showing??

[DateTimePicker](https://jsfiddle.net/AllDotnetQueries/xj5tefzj/1/)

```
 <div class="input-group date" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" size="16" name="startDate"  value="{{$internalVisitors->startDate}}" id="start" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show date time in your from then you must need to convert datetime format. 
laravel using carbon default. 
for example

```html
<div class="input-group date" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" size="16" name="startDate"  value="{{$internalVisitors->startDate->format('M d Y')}}" id="start" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="input-group date" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" size="16" name="startDate"  value="2018-06-12T19:30" id="start" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

first of all you can see date-time format working manually or not. if it's not working manually then first fix this. then you can fetch the data-time

Comment: it's showing `Call to a member function format() on string `

Comment: first of all you can try to entrire date value manually beacuse of ensure it's working fiine or not

<div class="input-group date" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" size="16" name="startDate"  value="2018-06-12T19:30" id="start" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
</div>

Comment: Date is inserting and it's showing in the table but not showing at `DateTime Picker text field`

Comment: I think you need to var_dump($internalVisitors->startDate) or dd($internalVisitors->startDate) 
then you can check what type of value he given

Comment: it's given `2018-11-06 18:27:00` ("Y-m-d H:i:s") this format.